# jQuery how to select elements not being .first() or .last()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I've got this code

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Web Development</a></li>
                <span data-landing_count="1">
                    <li class="subli"><a href="1.html">E-shop</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="2.html">Prezentations</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="3.html">Custom CMS</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="4.html">WordPress & Joomla!</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="5.html">Web apps</a></li>
                    <li class="subli lastsl"><a href="index-b.html">Design</a></li>
                </span>
            <li><a href="6.html">E-courses</a></li>
                <span data-landing_count="2">
                    <li class="subli"><a href="7.html">Design & Graphics</a></li>
                    <li class="subli lastsl"><a href="8.html">Web Development</a></li>
                </span>
            <li><a href="9.html">SEO</a></li>
                <span data-landing_count="3">
                    <li class="subli"><a href="91.html">On-page SEO</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="92.html">W3C validation</a></li>
                    <li class="subli"><a href="93.html">Linking</a></li>
                    <li class="subli lastsl"><a href="94.html"><img src="img/star.png" alt="star" width="12" class="star">Copywriting</a></li>
                </span>
            <li data-landing_count="4"><a href="95.html">Web hosting</a></li>
            <li data-landing_count="5"><a href="96.html"><img src="img/star.png" alt="star" width="12" class="star">Pricing</a></li>
            <li data-landing_count="6"><a href="97.html">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

There are 3 spans, I now i can target the first one by .first() and the last one with .last(). But how do I target the middle one?

Thanks for reply

Comment: An UL can only have LI children. So you should move your SPANs into the LIs unless you want chaos. Also, a LI can only be included in an UL or OL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('span').eq(1);
```

Using the `eq()` method, or the selector:

```
$('span:eq(1)');
```

Or:

```
$('span').slice(1,-1);
```

Note that your HTML is invalid, though: the *only* element that can wrap `li` elements is a `ul` or an `ol`.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`:eq` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).
- [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: +1 -- `.slice` is by far the fastest solution, and IMHO the cleanest as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul span').not(':first,:last');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Mc6Z/)

Please note that **your HTML is absolutely broken**. You *should learn HTML* first, because this will only lead to mysterious problems and downvoted StackOverflow questions.

`li` can only be the child of an `ul` or `ol`. Also, `ul` and `ol` can only have `li`s as their children. You cannot place `span`s in HTML the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with:

```
.eq(1)
```

it should work.

And if you want to take all elements you can use `for` when you iterate from secound on to pre-end element;

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML is **BAD**. Don't put `<span>` tags in between `<li>` tags. Only going to end in disaster.

Secondly, are you targeting these in order to provide different styles? If so, then why not make use of the css `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors. That way you can style the first and last rather than those in between.

Comment: +1 for general improvement suggestion, though this does not answer the question...

Comment: @Christoph Yeah it doesn't answer the question, but from my experience on here, a LOT of people are looking for the wrong solution to their problem. ;)

Comment: @TimBJames - It needs an awesome level of experience to say those words ! Kudos !!!

Comment: @Tim That's why my upvote;) Unfortunately a lot of people are just looking for c&p solutions.